# Trying to create a bash script, redirecting to youtube links

Tags: bash, scripts, browser

I'm trying to create a bash script.I never wrote bash in my life, I haven't even used Linux ever, so, after a bit of googling and thinking I decided to create a script that asks you the question "Which video do you wanna watch?"
and it giving you 3 options, 2 for 2 videos and 1 to close the script.After a bit of googling and studying, this is the code I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What type of video do you want to see?"

select video in video1 video2 close_program
case $video in
video1 ) xdg-open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQ9MpPIs1jM

video2 ) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2uWvrwq4T4

close_program ) exit;;


      esac
done
```

Of course, it's not perfect, so here I am, asking for tips to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve it by:

- putting it in a while loop (if user enter other choice)
- have shorter options:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do 
        printf 'What video do you want to see? (1, 2) or quit'
        read video

        case $video in
            *1 ) xdg-open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQ9MpPIs1jM;;
            *2 ) xdg-open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2uWvrwq4T4;;
            [qQ]*) exit;; # for quit, Quit...
            *) printf 'Please enter 1, 2 or quit'
    esac
done
```